# dagger is not providing a dependency to my subclass

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a BaseActivity and a ChildActivity.  In the BaseActivity I create my dependency graph:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject CompositeSubscription subscriptions;

AppComponent appComponent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .appModule(new AppModule(getApplication()))
            .build();
    appComponent.inject(this);
}
```

In the same package there is ChildActivity.  I also want to use subscriptions in the ChildActivity, but it is null:

```
public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity {

@Inject CompositeSubscription subscriptions;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    appComponent.inject(this);
}
```

My AppComponent looks like:

```
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(BaseActivity activity);
    void inject(IndexFragment fragment);
}
```

While my AppModule looks like

```
@Module
public final class AppModule {
    Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
    this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    CompositeSubscription provideSubscriptionManager() {
        return new CompositeSubscription();
    }
```

Why is subscriptions in ChildActivity null?  I'd like to add subscriptions from ChildActivity to that while unsubscribing all subscriptions in BaseActivity.

Comment: You should build your graph in Application class.

Comment: Is that necessary if I only have 1 activity and several fragments?  I don't need a custom Application class so I build the graph in the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dagger only knows about `BaseActivity` and has no knowledge about `ChildActivity` whatsoever. All you do is declare that `BaseActivity` should be field injected, here

```
void inject(BaseActivity activity); // mark BaseActivity for injection
```

This does not include its children. If you inject a child with this call you will inject only the parents fields.

To fix it you need to also register the child activity with Dagger so that Dagger will generate the proper code to inject your ChildActivitys fields.

```
void inject(ChildActivity activity); // register child as well
```

---

In your specific usecase it might be better for the child activity to access the parents property instead of declaring a property with the same name in the child, though.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought since ChildActivity called super.onCreate and a ChildActivity IS a BaseActivity I wouldn't have to register them twice.  I was wrong because when I @Inject CompositeSubscription in the ChildActivity it is null.

Answer (score 0):

In your `AppComponent` you have to add a `inject` method for each subclass:

```
@Component(modules = AppModule.class)  
@Singleton
public interface AppComponent {
  void inject(BaseActivity activity);
  void inject(ChildActivity activity);
  void inject(IndexFragment fragment);
}
```

As an improvement, you might want to use [Dagger-Android](https://google.github.io/dagger/android.html).